# Ignore special characters on StringTokenizer

Tags: java, special-characters, stringtokenizer

I want to ignore special characters like `,` `"` `;` `:` using string tokenizer.
For example, if I enter:

```
He said, "That's not a good idea."
```

output should be:

```
He
Said
that
s
not
a
good
idea
```

This is my current code

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter text to break :- ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = sc.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer url = new StringTokenizer(x, " ");              
        
        while(url.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            System.out.println(url.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) with the appropriate regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace that special characters with `regex` like this:

```
class Q_03 {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.print("Enter text to break :- ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("[|;:,'\"]", " ");
        StringTokenizer url = new StringTokenizer(x, " ");

        while (url.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(url.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

You can add to this regexp `"[;:,'\"]"` whatever symbols you want, but some special symbols (like `"`) must have been escaped with backslash `\"`.

Comment: it worked thanks. but when i put characters like | it gives a compilation error.

Comment: It works with `|`, I tested it. I updated my answer.